# Create a group of drawings to multiply into page

Tags: vb.net, printing

i wrote this code following MS guide on drawing object
the code create a label, now i want to make all this object to be repeated in 3 columns and 8 rows inside the printing page

```
 Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Dim drawFormat As New StringFormat
    drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

    Dim drawRect1 As New RectangleF(0, 60, 270, 20)
    Dim drawRect2 As New RectangleF(0, 80, 270, 20)
    Dim drawRect3 As New RectangleF(0, 115, 100, 20)
    Dim drawRect4 As New RectangleF(100, 110, 100, 30)
    Dim drawRect5 As New Rectangle(100, 110, 100, 30)


    e.Graphics.DrawString("OLD Code: " & TextBox2.Text, carattere, Brushes.Black, drawRect1, drawFormat)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("NEW Code: " & TextBox3.Text, carattere, Brushes.Black, drawRect2, drawFormat)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Quantità", carattere, Brushes.Black, drawRect3, drawFormat)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox4.Text, New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, drawRect4, drawFormat)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Brushes.Black), drawRect5)


    Dim newImage As Image = My.Resources.Immagine
    Dim x As Integer = 47
    Dim y As Integer = 5
    Dim width As Integer = 180
    Dim height As Integer = 50
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, x, y, width, height)

End Sub
```

so, there is a container that can i use to store all the things and repeat? or i have to write all the code for all the labels?

Comment: Create a procedure to handle the repeated code - maybe 2 (one for rows, one for columns).  That code is leaking though - you are not disposing the image you create

Comment: @Plutonix That image is coming from resources.  I don't think you dispose that.

Comment: @LarsTech Each time you reference them it creates a new object.  Drill into the code and you can see it creating stuff

Comment: ok, but how? all the drawstring/image have point referred to top left of the page, can i make a "dim LBL as New somecontaineridontknow" and store in it all the part, in a way that all is referenced to the top left of a "virtual rectangle" e copy this rectangle usig 2 nested for cycle to complete the page?

Comment: The question lacks specifics but `make all this object to be repeated in 3 columns` means that you should be able to calculate 2 of the columns as an offset of the first, so just pass an indicator for which column.  Maybe all the  method does is calculate one or all those RectFs (again, *vague*).

Comment: @Plutonix It's annoying that you would have to drill into the code to have to learn that.  The end user didn't put the word "new" anywhere in their image code.